# Webflux and keycloak using for method security level @Preauthorize custom claim in jwt instead of default scope

Tags: java, spring-security, keycloak, spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2

As per title I am setting up webflux config like this

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
String jwkSetUri = "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/certs";
@Bean 
public ReactiveJwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {

return 
ReactiveJwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation("http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo");
}
 @Bean

public SecurityWebFilterChain configure(ServerHttpSecurity http) {

     http.authorizeExchange()

           
            .oauth2Login()

            .and()
          .
            ...
             .oauth2ResourceServer()
             .jwt()

    .jwkSetUri(jwkSetUri)

            // .jwtDecoder(jwtDecoder())

             .jwtAuthenticationConverter(grantedAuthoritiesExtractor());
            return http.build();
}

@Bean

Converter<Jwt, Mono<AbstractAuthenticationToken>> grantedAuthoritiesExtractor() {

    GrantedAuthoritiesExtractor extractor = new GrantedAuthoritiesExtractor();

    return new ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverterAdapter(extractor);

}
static class GrantedAuthoritiesExtractor

       extends  JwtAuthenticationConverter {


    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> extractAuthorities(Jwt jwt) {

        Collection<?> authorities = (Collection<?>)

                jwt.getClaims().getOrDefault("roles", Collections.emptyList());


        return authorities.stream()

                .map(Object::toString)

                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)

                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

with the following application.yml

```
security:
   oauth2:

     client:
       provider:
         keycloak-local:
           issuer-uri: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo
       registration:
         keycloak-local:
           client-id: some-id
           client-secret: ...

     resourceserver:
       jwt:
     
         issuer-uri: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo
         jwk-set-uri: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid- 
         connect/certs
```

the token format is like that

```
"realm_access": {
"roles": [
 "offline_access",
  "uma_authorization"
  ]
   },
 "resource_access": {
 "someclient": {
  "roles": [
    "uma_protection"
   ]
  },
  "account": {
    "roles": [
    "manage-account",
    "manage-account-links",
    "view-profile"
  ]
   }
   },
   "scope": "profile  email ",
   "organizationId": "605b74813bd72c65a24a1704",
   "accountId": "605b74813bd72c65a24a1709",
   "email_verified": false,
   "roles": [
   "ROLE_ADMIN"    
     ],
   "preferred_username": "someUsername",
   "userId": "605b74813bd72c65a24a1706",
   "email": "email.com"
    }`
```

and of course the "roles" array is the one that I would like ideally to access(is the role that I define in my DB).

After that setup it seems that nothing has changed .
So in my controller I tried to use the
@Preauthorize annotation to access to some method but it keeps working with the scope claim.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SCOPE_email')")
```

Does anyone knows what I am missing?  Please note that I refer to official documentation but also to [this tutorial](https://blog.ineat-group.com/2019/01/securiser-vos-apis-spring-webflux-avec-keycloak-et-oauth2/).
for webflux.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Spring Security converts the items in the `scope` or `scp` claim and uses the `SCOPE_` prefix. If your application is a pure **OAuth2 Resource Server**, you can change both conventions by defining a custom `ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverter` bean.

For example, to export authorities from a `roles` scope and using the `` prefix (since `ROLE_` is already part of your role name), you can define the following bean. Spring Security will pick it up automatically, you don't need to reference it from your SecurityWebFilterChain configuration.

```
@Bean
public ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
    var jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
    jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_");
    jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("roles");

    var jwtAuthenticationConverter = new ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverter();
    jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(
            new ReactiveJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverterAdapter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter));

    return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
}
```

Since your application is also configured as an **OAuth2 Client** (with `oauth2Login()`), then you need a different approach. You can either define a `GrantedAuthoritiesMapper` or an `OAuth2UserService`. Examples for both options can be found in the [Spring Security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2login-advanced-map-authorities).

Comment: Hi Thomas thanks for the answer. I tried to get rid in my SecurityWebFilterChain  of the .jwtAuthenticationConverter(converter()) and used that beans that you suggested. However the @Preauthorize is working still with the "scope" claim. Am I missing some jwtDecoder or other config on keycloak side according to that? Please note that the roles array is like that roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_OTHER] is not a space separated value like the scope claim but I am not sure its for that.

Comment: I updated my answer (my previous code snippet was for non-reactive apps, now it should be correct). Can you try again?

Comment: Still nothing the realmName is null and just the claim name is changed (see my EDIT) but the @Preauthorize works still with the scope claim. Am I missing some jwtDecoder ?

Comment: I hadn't notice your application is configured to be both an OAuth2 Client and OAuth2 Resource Server, my mistake. The JwtAuthenticationConverter approach works only for pure resource servers. In your case, you need to define either a GrantedAuthoritiesMapper or an OAuth2UserService. I updated my answer to include information for all those scenarios.

Comment: I am trying leaving both resource server and OAuth2 client(i tried also to get rid of the first one) and implementing  a Bean GrantedAuthoritiesMapper but still nothing (pls see EDIT2 if something looks wrong)

Comment: Pls note that I made the resource server config(applicaiton.yml+security config) in order to have the authorithies mapped to the custom claim but if its possible to do just with the Oauth2Client good to know.I think there should be another issue because the debug is always null

Comment: Keycloak, by default, adds the roles claim to the Access Token only. In your case, you probably want the claim to be added to the UserInfo object as well. You can do that from the Keycloak GUI: "Client Scopes > roles > Mappers > realm roles" and then enable UserInfo. Also, you can remove the Resource Server configuration and the ReactiveJwtDecoder bean. As a reference, you can check out this app demonstrating OAuth2 Login with custom authorities extracted from UserInfo. https://github.com/ThomasVitale/spring-security-examples/tree/main/oauth2/login-user-authorities-reactive

Comment: After few other attempts finally is working.Many thanks! I will mark your answer as correct